# How can I cause Simple Injector to use different concrete classes for the same interface, but with different classes

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I can do this with StructureMap using Constructor Injection. However I cannot find a way to do this with Simple Injector. Here is some code that illustrates this (sorry for the length)

I've looked at the lambda in the `Register` method, but can't seem to understand how to call a single application wide instance of the container to get the one instance I need.

These are the object graphs I wish to construct:

````cs
var bannerTalker =
    new LoudMouth(
        new ConsoleShouter(), // Implements IConsoleVoicer
        new ObnoxiousBannerGenerator());

var plainTalker = 
    new TimidSpeaker(
        new ConsoleWhisperer());  // Implements IConsoleVoicer

Here's the code:

``` c#
public interface IConsoleVoicer
{
    void SaySomething(string whatToSay);
}

public class ConsoleWhisperer : IConsoleVoicer
{
    public void SaySomething(string whatToSay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(whatToSay?.ToLower());
    }
}

public class ConsoleShouter : IConsoleVoicer
{
    public void SaySomething(string whatToSay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(whatToSay?.ToUpper());
    }
}

public interface IBannerGenerator
{
    string GetBanner();
}

public class ObnoxiousBannerGenerator : IBannerGenerator
{
    public string GetBanner()
    {
        return "OBNOXIOUS";
    }
}

public interface IBannerTalker
{
    void SayWithBanner(string somethingToSay);
}

public class LoudMouth : IBannerTalker
{
    private IConsoleVoicer Voicer { get; set; }
    private IBannerGenerator BannerGenerator { get; set; }

    public LoudMouth(
        IConsoleVoicer concoleVoicer, IBannerGenerator bannerGenerator)
    {
        Voicer = concoleVoicer;
        BannerGenerator = bannerGenerator;
    }

    public void SayWithBanner(string somethingToSay)
    {
        Voicer.SaySomething(string.Format("{0}:{1}",
            BannerGenerator.GetBanner(), somethingToSay));
    }
}

public interface IPlainTalker
{
    void SayIt(string somethingToSay);
}

public class TimidSpeaker : IPlainTalker
{
    private IConsoleVoicer Voicer { get; set; }

    public TimidSpeaker(IConsoleVoicer concoleVoicer)
    {
        Voicer = concoleVoicer;
    }

    public void SayIt(string somethingToSay)
    {
        Voicer.SaySomething(somethingToSay);
    }
}
````

And this is what I've tried:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register<IBannerGenerator, ObnoxiousBannerGenerator>();

    container.Register<IPlainTalker, TimidSpeaker>();
    container.Register<IBannerTalker, LoudMouth>();

    //HERE IS THE DILEMMA! How do I assign
    // to IBannerTalker a A LoudMouth contructed with a ConsoleShouter,
    // and to IPlainTalkerTalker a A TimidSpeaker contructed with a ConsoleWhisperer 

    //container.Register<IConsoleVoicer, ConsoleShouter>();
    container.Register<IConsoleVoicer, ConsoleWhisperer>();

    var bannerTalker = container.GetInstance<IBannerTalker>();
    var plainTalker = container.GetInstance<IPlainTalker>();

    bannerTalker.SayWithBanner("i am a jerk");
    plainTalker.SayIt("people like me");
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [RegisterConditional](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ric .Net is right in pointing you at the `RegisterConditional` methods. The following registrations complete your quest:

```cs
container.Register<IBannerGenerator, ObnoxiousBannerGenerator>();

container.Register<IPlainTalker, TimidSpeaker>();
container.Register<IBannerTalker, LoudMouth>();

container.RegisterConditional<IConsoleVoicer, ConsoleShouter>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(LoudMouth));
container.RegisterConditional<IConsoleVoicer, ConsoleWhisperer>(
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(TimidSpeaker));
```

Comment: Disco! This worked. I was unaware of the `RegisterConditional` method.